# Explanation of printing current month {date +%B}

Tags: bash, date, unix

The command to print the current month is:

```
date +%B
```

Now why is there a `+` and a `%` in front of `B`?

Does `+` mean insert the entire contents of a file and `%` mean bring program to foreground processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` means that the date should be formatted.

The `%B` is a format specifier that means that `date` should print the full month.

For more information on `date` and format specifiers, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29#Formatting).